# Use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for some part of unique mapping key

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have table as shown below

```
   ItemAttMapID    ItemAttributeID    VendorID    vItemID    Qty
        1                4               1           2       60
        2                4               2           3       10
        3                3               5           5       20
```

In this table `ItemAttMapID` is `auto_increment` `primary_key`

and `ItemAttributeID, VendorID, VItemID` is `Unique Mapping`.

I used following query

```
INSERT INTO `client`.`mapping`  
(`ItemAttMapID`, `ItemAttributeID`, `VendorID`, `vItemID`, `Qty`)  

VALUES  
(NULL, 4, '2', '3', '70'),  
(NULL, 3, '5', '5', '80')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Qty = VALUES(Qty);
```

It gives me proper result which I want
but when I used following query instead of updating the perticular record it inserts the new one.

```
INSERT INTO `client`.`mapping`  
(`ItemAttMapID`, `ItemAttributeID`, `VendorID`, `vItemID`, `Qty`)  

VALUES  
(NULL, 2, '5', '5', '80')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Qty = VALUES(Qty);
```

and change in table is like this

```
   ItemAttMapID    ItemAttributeID    VendorID    vItemID    Qty
        1                4               1           2       60
        2                4               2           3       10
        3                3               5           5       20
        4                2               5           5       80
```

I want the 3rd number row to update but It is inserting a new record to table.

How can I achieve this using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

**EDIT:**

I want to check only, if `VendorID` and `vItemID` is already present then update the record ( NOT THE `ItemAttributeID`) using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE..

Because if I put `ItemAttributeID` same along with `VendorID` and `vItemID` in query then it updates the record otherwise its inserting new record.

Comment: why not just check with exists and do an if statment for update and insert?

Comment: actually I was using it...
but want to try it using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE